# Why letters appear bold in equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, bold

I want to write out the following equations,

```
\begin{equation}
  \bf{V} = F(\boldsymbol{\sigma}) + \bf{e}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \Delta \bf{V} \approx J \cdot \Delta \boldsymbol{\sigma}
\end{equation}
```

For some reason the F and the second Delta are appearing bold, although I do not want them to be bold. How can I resolve this issue?[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Advice: the command `\bf` is depreciated. For modern LaTeX documents you must use `\mathbf{...}`.

Comment: Not only `\bf` is deprecated: its syntax would be `{\bf V}`, but `\mathbf{V}` is the correct form.

Comment: @Sebastiano Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have add an answer.

Comment: @egreg YOU ARE ALWAYS AUTHORIZZATED TO EDIT MY QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\bf` is deprecated. Besides it should be `{\bf V}`, but the correct form is `\mathbf{V}`.

Also `\bm` is better than `\boldsymbol` (requires the `bm` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{V} = F(\bm{\sigma}) + \mathbf{e}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \Delta \mathbf{V} \approx J \cdot \Delta \bm{\sigma}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Prof. unfortunately in my profile there is not the motto of the "Barbiere di Siviglia" :-). I'm lent when I think and write. Thank you so much for your cooperation. I do not know what is the unicode symbol of the bow but you keep in mind that there is.